# Faster method for adjusting PIL pixel values

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, chromakey

I'm writing a script to chroma key (green screen) and composite some videos using Python and PIL (pillow). I can key the 720p images, but there's some left over green spill. Understandable but I'm writing a routine to remove that spill...however I'm struggling with how long it's taking. I can probably get better speeds using numpy tricks, but I'm not that familiar with it. Any ideas?

Here's my despill routine. It takes a PIL image and a sensitivity number but I've been leaving that at 1 so far...it's been working well. I'm coming in at just over 4 seconds for a 720p frame to remove this spill. For comparison, the chroma key routine runs in about 2 seconds per frame.

```
def despill(img, sensitivity=1):
    """
    Blue limits green.
    """
    start = time.time()
    print '\t[*] Starting despill'
    width, height = img.size
    num_channels = len(img.getbands())
    out = Image.new("RGBA", img.size, color=0)
    for j in range(height):
        for i in range(width):
            #r,g,b,a = data[j,i]
            r,g,b,a = img.getpixel((i,j))
            if g > (b*sensitivity):
                out_g = (b*sensitivity)
            else:
                out_g = g
            # end if

            out.putpixel((i,j), (r,out_g,b,a))
        # end for
    # end for
    out.show()
    print '\t[+] done.'
    print '\t[!] Took: %0.1f seconds' % (time.time()-start)
    exit()
    return out
# end despill
```

Instead of putpixel, I tried to write the output pixel values to a numpy array then convert the array to a PIL image, but that was averaging just over 5 seconds...so this was faster somehow. I know putpixel isn't the snappiest option but I'm at a loss...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`putpixel` is slow, and loops like that are even slower, since they are run by the Python interpreter, which is slow as hell. The usual solution is to convert immediately the image to a numpy array and solve the problem with vectorized operations on it, which run in heavily optimized C code. In your case I would do something like:

```
arr = np.array(img)
g = arr[:,:,1]
bs = arr[:,:,2]*sensitivity
cond = g>bs
arr[:,:,1] = cond*bs + (~cond)*g
out = Image.fromarray(arr)
```

(it may not be correct and I'm sure it can be optimized way better, this is just a sketch)

Comment: Fantastic! That's INSANELY faster. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, and written properly in C can be made probably several times faster. BTW, there was a typo in the formula that I fixed now, you should update your code if you already copied it.